# How to use MapCircle outwith Mapobject [in a function]?

Tags: qt, dictionary, qml

I want ask, how I can use the MapCircle outwith the Map {} object. I want write a function, which will draw a way, and I thought, that I can do somethink like that:

```
function putWay (way)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < getLatitude.count - 1; i++ )
    {
        way.center {
            longtitude: getLongtitude.get(i).longtitude
            latitude: getLatitude.get(i).latitude

        }
    }
}
```

Way = MapCircel

getLatitude = listView, where are my data (Latitude) from DB

getLongtitude, this same but Longtitude

And way would be a MapCircel id, but it doesn't work. I think becouse of using the Map properity outwith the Map object, but maybe is a way to using the Map properity outwith Map object? Maybe a pointer or somethink like that? Maybe I can create my own object/properity?

Comment: "And way would be a MapCircel id", also way is a Mapcircel, and getLatitude is the ListView, where a have my data feom DataBase

Comment: I want display this data on the map. Draw a way by using this data, which I get from database. And i wrote this data to listView.

Comment: Yes, one row is a one coordinate for the mapCircel.

Comment: https://github.com/DragonCoderProject/Semestralwork.git     here is the project. The function is pain at the bottom

Comment: If u need comments in the code or somethink, I can do this

Comment: Yes, I am using the facharbeit.db and I have problem with loading the data. I thought, that I did mistake by writing the name of table, but I checked it 3 times. It is one of mistake, that I can't read datas from the facharbeit.db. And the another is with using the mapCircel outwith Map

Comment: So I need only to copy the files and using it for my database, but what with the mapcircel?

Comment: Need I only sqlquerymodel.h, or should i read this one: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_a_QSqlQueryModel_in_QML, but i think, that it is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were a single item, the solution is as follows:

```
way.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(getLongtitude.get(i).latitude, getLatitude.get(i).longtitude)
```

But in your case it is not ideal because the number of points is variable.

When you have a variable amount of data it is better to use a model, I see that you wanted to use LocalStorage but unfortunately it does not allow to read a sqlite by the path, so in this case you must implement a model, in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469463/6622587) and implement it.

Then you have to use a MapItemView and pass it to the MapCircle as a delegate.

```
SqlQueryModel{
        id: querymodel
        query: "select * from coordinates"
    }
// ...
Map {
    // ...
    MapItemView{
        model: querymodel
        delegate:  MapCircle {
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)
            radius: 1.0
            color: 'blue'
            border.width: 1
        }
    }
```

The above is the essential but I also took the liberty to improve your code so you can find it [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/53964703).

Comment: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude), and as latitude and logitude I use my Sqlquerymodel, and then the will be drawn?

Comment: Can you explain me short, when the localstorage would be fine to use?

Comment: Oh okay, now i understand that. I will analyze this and when I will have question, i will ask. First thanks for your help, and sorry for my english, beacouse I know, that ti doesn't help to analyze my problem and help me

Comment: Can i do it so, that the points will drawn first after button clicked? I tried querymodel.cente = QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude), but it doesn't work, need I to creat a function?

Comment: Okay, but I did it so, and the Circel wans't drawn. I check it second time. I unterstand that the SqlQueryModel is only for the query to database and nothink more. Maybe I did a mistake by writing the name, I will check it, thanks

Comment: I have question. After Compiling and runing my project in Qt, I can draw the points on the Map, but when I start the programm without Qt, then it doesn't work. What can be the problem?

Comment: yes I mean QtCreator. I compiled my app in the QtCreator and all works, but when I try to run my app without QtCreator, then I can't draw the MapCircel on the map.

Comment: Linux Mint 19 (Tara) 64 bit