# QSqlTableModel to qml list coming through multiple times

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new and trying to learn qt and qml but I cannot find a way to solve this problem.

I have a QSqlTableModel with only 4 rows of test data, but I would like to convert distinct values from 1 column (of which there is only 1 value) into a list for a qml ListModel.

I have this `Q_PROPERTY(QStringList distinctSemesters READ getSemesterList NOTIFY semesterChanged)` in my SqlDataModel.h file, with this in my sqldatamodel.cpp

```
QStringList  SqlDataModel::getSemesterList() const
{
    QStringList  mySemesters;
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM results");
    while (query.next()) {
        QString currentSemester = query.value(0).toString();
        mySemesters << currentSemester;
    }
    return mySemesters;
}
```

Which returns a QStringList of length 1. I am trying to read this into my qml with

```
ListView {
    model: SqlDataModel {
                    id: myModel
                }
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
                width: parent.width
                text: myModel.distinctSemesters
            }
}
```

Which works in getting the String from the getSemesterList() function. But the String gets repeated in the listview 4 times (the size of my tablemodel). I have checked this and added more rows to the test table, which continues to repeat the same string more times in my listview.

From my limited understanding, I am guessing that this will always be the case because the listview is taking its size from the model - which is the size of the qsl table. I have no idea about how to go about this, can anyone else point me in the correct direction?

My current thoughts are to create a new sqlmodel to bring into the qml (but I need to read+write so I believe sqltablemodel is good for that), or should I try to fix qml side with javascript. I looked into  it in javascript but when I tried

```
property ListModel distinctSemesters;
Component.onCompleted: {
              console.log(distinctSemesters)
```

I kept getting errors that the distinctSemesters was undefined.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

below (i hope) is a reproducible example. I have used some online resources to guide this.
main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initDatabase();

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<SqlDataModel>("GradesSqlDataModel", 1, 0, "SqlDataModel");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

SqlDataModel.h

```
class SqlDataModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString semester READ getsemester WRITE setSemester NOTIFY semesterChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList distinctSemesters READ getSemesterList NOTIFY semesterChanged)

public:
    SqlDataModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    QStringList getSemesterList() const;
    QString getsemester() const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

signals:
    void semesterChanged();
};
```

SqlDataModel.cpp

```
SqlDataModel::SqlDataModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSqlTableModel(parent)
{
    createTable();
    setTable("Results");
    setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    select();

}

QStringList  SqlDataModel::getSemesterList() const
{
    QStringList  mySemesters;
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM results");
    while (query.next()) {
        QString currentSemester = query.value(0).toString();
        mySemesters << currentSemester;
        qDebug() << currentSemester;
    }
    qDebug() << "length :" <<mySemesters.length();
    return mySemesters;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> SqlDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> dataNames;
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole] = "ID";
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole + 1] = "Semester";
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole + 2] = "CourseTitle";
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole + 3] = "TestWeight";
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole + 4] = "TestName";
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole + 5] = "Result";
    dataNames[Qt::UserRole + 6] = "OutOf";
    qDebug() << "DataNames" << dataNames;
    return dataNames;
}
QVariant SqlDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << "settingData";
    if (role < Qt::UserRole)
        return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);

    const QSqlRecord sqlRecord = record(index.row());
    return sqlRecord.value(role - Qt::UserRole);
}
```

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window;
    visible: true;
    width: 640;
    height: 600;
    title: qsTr("TEST")

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
        height: window.height
        interactive: true

        ListView {
                  model: SqlDataModel {
                    id: myModel
                }
                delegate: ItemDelegate {
                         width: parent.width
                         text: myModel.distinctSemesters
               }
       }
}
```

and my Results sql table looks like this (only with an ID primary key first):

```
query.exec("INSERT INTO results (Semester, CourseTitle, TestWeight, TestName, Result, OutOf) VALUES ('Spring 2020', 'Course 1', '10', 'Exam 1', 50, 100)");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO results (Semester, CourseTitle, TestWeight, TestName, Result, OutOf) VALUES ('Spring 2020', 'Course 1', '33', 'Exam 2', 70, 100)");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO results (Semester, CourseTitle, TestWeight, TestName, Result, OutOf) VALUES ('Spring 2020', 'Course 2', '25', 'Exam 1', 0, 100)");
    query.exec("INSERT INTO results (Semester, CourseTitle, TestWeight, TestName, Result, OutOf) VALUES ('Spring 2020', 'Course 2', '5', 'Quiz 1', 5, 20)");
```

Comment: Do you also observe repeated elements after the while: `while(query.next())){...}` `qDebug() << mySemesters;`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I don't know how much of an example to give, Ill try to get the other bits of code together when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

In your case the QSqlTableModel loads all the rows of the table since there is no filter so it will have 4 rows so any view that uses it will also show those 4 rows so the ListView shows 4 rows. Why does each row show the same information? Well, because in each item you have the delegate show the different "Semester" that are always "Spring 2020".

**Solution:**

In this case it is not necessary to use a QSqlTableModel since a QSqlQueryModel is enough to allow filtering from QML, so for this you can use the model of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469463/6622587). So it will only be enough to place it in export to QML and use it.

```cpp
qmlRegisterType<SqlQueryModel>("GradesSqlDataModel", 1, 0, "SqlQueryModel");
```

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import GradesSqlDataModel 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640;
    height: 600;

    SqlQueryModel{
        id: sqlquerymodel
        query: "SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM results"
    }
    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
        height: window.height
        interactive: true
        ListView{
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: sqlquerymodel
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                width: parent.width
                text: model.Semester
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: drawer.visible = true
}
```

[image]

<sub>The full example can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/59847739).</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes total sense. I looked at QSqlQueryModel, but from what I can see the QSqlQueryModel is read-only, and I would like to be able to write as well in other areas of my app(and hopefully update this list)? Or am I able to write to the database directly with SQL language in the query?

Comment: @AdamLaird QSqlTableModel is not the only way to write, as you seem to know you can use QSqlQuery. Within your requirements you do not indicate any of it so I will ignore it in my answer. If you have new problems as it seems then create a new post as indicated by the SO rules.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer in the question that I need it to write as well (it was in the original question though). Thanks for your help though, I was not aware that I can write within the QSqlQueryModel.