# CheckBoxes and SQLite in QML

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, listview, qml

I have a listview in frontend which has some texts to show `firstname`, `lastname`, `city` and... plus a checkbox item for each record.

I want to bind this checkbox item to a `selected` field in database which has type of `INTEGER`.

The problem is that I don't know how to bind checkbox item to `selected` data field in SQLite database!

For showing texts in QML frontend simply I used a Text item with text property set to proper roleid e.g `text: firstname` or `text: lastname`...
But if I do something similar for checkbox item I will get binding loop and program tends to crash!

Should I need to reimplement setData function?

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Here is the example:

database.h:

```
#ifndef Database_H
#define Database_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

class Database : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Database(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Database();
    void connectToDatabase();
private:
    QSqlDatabase db;
private:
    bool openDatabase();
    bool restoreDatabase();
    void closeDatabase();
    bool createTable();
public slots:
    bool inserIntoTable(const QStringList &data); // Adding entries to the table
    bool modifyTable(int id, bool selection);
    bool removeRecord(int id); // Removing records from the table on its id
};
#endif // Database_H
```

database.cpp:

```
#include "database.h"
#include "DatabaseColumns.h"

Database::Database(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent){}
Database::~Database(){}

void Database::connectToDatabase()
{
    !QFile{DATABASE_NAME}.exists() ? this->restoreDatabase() : this->openDatabase();
}
bool Database::restoreDatabase()
{
    if(this->openDatabase()){
        return (this->createTable()) ? true : false;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to restore the Database";
        return false;
    }
}
bool Database::openDatabase()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName(DATABASE_HOSTNAME);
    db.setDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME);
    if(db.open()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void Database::closeDatabase()
{
    db.close();
}
bool Database::createTable()
{
    QString str;
    int counter = 0;
    for (const QString& tempStr: DATABASE_COLUMNS){
        switch (counter) {
        case 0:
            str += tempStr + " " + DATABASE_ID_TYPE ", ";
            break;
        case 1:
            str += tempStr + " " + DATABASE_CHECKED_TYPE ", ";
            break;
        case DATABASE_LENGTH - 1:
            str += tempStr + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL";
            break;
        default:
            str += tempStr + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ";
        }
        ++counter;
    }
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec( "CREATE TABLE " TABLE " (" + str + ")"))
    {
        qDebug() << "Database: error of create " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool Database::inserIntoTable(const QStringList &data)
{
    QSqlQuery query; QString str{"INSERT INTO " TABLE " ("};
    int counter = 0;
    for (const QString& tempStr: DATABASE_COLUMNS)
    {
        switch (counter)
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case DATABASE_LENGTH - 1:
            str += tempStr;
            break;
        default:
            str += tempStr + ", ";
        }
        ++counter;
    }
    str += ") VALUES (";
    counter = 0;
    for (const QString& tempStr: DATABASE_COLUMNS)
    {
        switch (counter)
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case DATABASE_LENGTH - 1:
            str += ":" + tempStr + ")";
            break;
        default:
            str += ":" + tempStr + ", ";
        }
        ++counter;
    }
    query.prepare(str);
    counter = 0;
    for (const QString& tempStr: DATABASE_COLUMNS)
    {
        if (tempStr != "id") {
            query.bindValue(":" + tempStr, data[counter]);
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    if(!query.exec())
    {
        qDebug() << "error insert into " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Database::modifyTable(int id, bool selection)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec("UPDATE " TABLE " SET selected = " + QString::number(selection) + " WHERE id = " + QString::number(id)))
    {
        qDebug() << "error delete row " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool Database::removeRecord(int id)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec("DELETE FROM " TABLE " WHERE id = " + QString::number(id)))
    {
        qDebug() << "error delete row " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

DatabaseColumns.h:

```
#ifndef DATABASECOLUMNS_H
#define DATABASECOLUMNS_H

#include <array>
#include <QString>

#define DATABASE_HOSTNAME "localhost"
#define DATABASE_NAME "mydatabase.db"
#define TABLE "MyTable"

#define DATABASE_LENGTH 3
#define DATABASE_ID_TYPE "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
#define DATABASE_CHECKED_TYPE "INTEGER"
#define DATABASE_COLUMNS std::array<QString, DATABASE_LENGTH>{\
                                    "id",\
                                    "selected",\
                                    "firstname"}

#endif // DATABASECOLUMNS_H
```

listmodel.h:

```
#ifndef LISTMODEL_H
#define LISTMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

class ListModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
signals:
public slots:
    void updateModel();
    int getId(int row);
};

#endif // LISTMODEL_H
```

listmodel.cpp:

```
#include "listmodel.h"
#include "DatabaseColumns.h"
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QSqlError>

ListModel::ListModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
    updateModel();
}
QVariant ListModel::data(const QModelIndex &inputIndex, int role) const {
    int columnId = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
    QModelIndex modelIndex = index(inputIndex.row(), columnId);
    return QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ListModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    int i = Qt::UserRole + 1;
    for(const QString& str: DATABASE_COLUMNS){
        roles[i] = str.toUtf8();
        ++i;
    }
    return roles;
}
void ListModel::updateModel()
{
    QString str; int counter = 0;
    for(const QString& tempStr: DATABASE_COLUMNS){
        if (counter != DATABASE_LENGTH - 1)
            str += tempStr + ", ";
        else str += tempStr;
        ++counter;
    }
    setQuery("SELECT " + str + " FROM " TABLE);
}
int ListModel::getId(int row)
{
    return data(index(row, 0), Qt::UserRole + 1).toInt();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 600
    TextField{
        id: name
        anchors.bottom: acceptKey.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.margins: 100
        placeholderText: "input the name"
    }

    Button{
        id: acceptKey
        text: "Accept"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            database.inserIntoTable([false, name.text])
            myModel.updateModel()
        }
    }
    ListView {
        id: tableView
        clip: true
        anchors.top: acceptKey.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: 300
        height: width
        property int textWidth: 100
        contentWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width
        contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
        headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
        flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick
        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: "Blue"
            opacity: 0.2
        }
        header: Rectangle {
            property alias checkState: headerCheckBox.checkState
            height: tableHead.implicitHeight + seperator.height
            width: tableHead.implicitWidth
            z: 2
            Row {
                id: tableHead
                spacing: 100
                layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
                CheckBox {id: headerCheckBox; indicator.width: 20; indicator.height: 20}
                Text {width: 50; text: "Name" }
            }
            ToolSeparator {
                id: seperator
                height: 7
                padding: 0
                topPadding: 0
                bottomPadding: 0
                anchors { top: tableHead.bottom; right: parent.right }
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                width: tableHead.implicitWidth
            }
        }
        model: myModel
        delegate: Item{
            width: parent.width
            height: rowId.implicitHeight
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: tableView.currentIndex = index
            }
            Row {
                id: rowId
                spacing: 100
                layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
                CheckBox {
                    id: checkBox
                    indicator.width: 20; indicator.height: 20
                    onCheckStateChanged: {
                        if (checkState === Qt.Checked){
                            console.log("Currently checked!")
                            database.modifyTable(myModel.getId(tableView.currentIndex), true)
                        }else{
                            console.log("Unchecked!")
                            database.modifyTable(myModel.getId(tableView.currentIndex), false)
                        }
                        myModel.updateModel()
                    }
                }
                Text {
                    width: 50
                    text: firstname
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include "database.h"
#include "listmodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Database database;
    database.connectToDatabase();
    ListModel model;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("database", &database);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

The problem is when I select checkbox foreach record they are not toggled on and stay off forever!

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your suggestion! I added a little example of how this problem raise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469463/6622587), I have created the SqlQueryModel model that creates roles according to the query, making it easier to handle the model from QML, on the other hand I have created SqlQueryManager, which is a QObject that allows you to easily manage queries from QML. Considering the above, the solution is:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>

#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>

#include <QDebug>

namespace CONSTANTS {
constexpr char TABLE_NAME[] = "MyTable";
constexpr char DATABASE_NAME[] = "mydatabase.db";
}

static bool createConnection() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(CONSTANTS::DATABASE_NAME);
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug()<< QObject::tr("Cannot open database") <<
                   QObject::tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                               "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                               "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                               "to build it.\n\n"
                               "Click Cancel to exit.");
        return false;
    }
    // create table
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec(QString(R"(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %1 (
                           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                           firstname TEXT,
                           selected INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (selected IN (0,1))
                           ))").arg(CONSTANTS::TABLE_NAME))){
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

class SqlQueryModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QSqlQueryModel::QSqlQueryModel;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const{
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++)
            roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
        return roles;
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
        if (!index.isValid())
            return QVariant();
        if (role < Qt::UserRole)
            return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        return QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void update(){
        setQuery(query().lastQuery());
    }
};

class SqlQueryManager: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    Q_INVOKABLE static bool exec(const QString & query){
        QSqlQuery q(query);
        if(!q.exec()){
            qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool exec(){
        if(!m_query.exec()){
            qDebug() << m_query.lastError().text();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool prepare(const QString &query){
        return m_query.prepare(query);
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void bindValue(const QString &placeholder, const QVariant &val){
        m_query.bindValue(placeholder, val);
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void bindValue(int pos, const QVariant &val){
        m_query.bindValue(pos, val);
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void addBindValue(const QVariant &val){
        m_query.addBindValue(val);
    }
private:
    QSqlQuery m_query;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    if(!createConnection()){
        return -1;
    }
    SqlQueryModel model;
    model.setQuery(QStringLiteral("SELECT * FROM %1").arg(CONSTANTS::TABLE_NAME));

    SqlQueryManager manager;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("queryModel", &model);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("queryManager", &manager);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("tableName", CONSTANTS::TABLE_NAME);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 600
    TextField{
        id: name
        anchors.bottom: acceptKey.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.margins: 100
        placeholderText: "input the name"
    }

    Button{
        id: acceptKey
        text: "Accept"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            queryManager.prepare("INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(selected, firstname) VALUES (?, ?)")
            queryManager.addBindValue(false);
            queryManager.addBindValue(name.text)
            queryManager.exec()
            queryModel.update()
            name.text = ""
        }
    }
    ListView {
        id: tableView
        clip: true
        anchors.top: acceptKey.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: 300
        height: width
        property int textWidth: 100
        contentWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width
        contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
        headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
        flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick
        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: "Blue"
            opacity: 0.2
        }
        header: Rectangle {
            property alias checkState: headerCheckBox.checkState
            height: tableHead.implicitHeight + seperator.height
            width: tableHead.implicitWidth
            z: 2
            Row {
                id: tableHead
                spacing: 100
                layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
                CheckBox {id: headerCheckBox; indicator.width: 20; indicator.height: 20}
                Text {width: 50; text: "Name" }
            }
            ToolSeparator {
                id: seperator
                height: 7
                padding: 0
                topPadding: 0
                bottomPadding: 0
                anchors { top: tableHead.bottom; right: parent.right }
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                width: tableHead.implicitWidth
            }
        }
        model: queryModel
        delegate: Item{
            width: parent.width
            height: rowId.implicitHeight
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: tableView.currentIndex = index
            }
            Row {
                id: rowId
                spacing: 100
                layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
                CheckBox {
                    id: checkBox
                    checked: model.selected
                    indicator.width: 20; indicator.height: 20
                    onCheckStateChanged: {
                        if(model.selected != checked){ // @disable-check M126
                            queryManager.prepare("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET selected = ? WHERE id = ?")
                            queryManager.addBindValue(checked);
                            queryManager.addBindValue(model.id);
                            queryManager.exec();
                            queryModel.update();
                        }
                    }
                }
                Text {
                    width: 50
                    text: model.firstname
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I found a simpler solution for this: I just change onCheckStateChanged signal to simple onClicked signal and now everything work perfectly now.